# Display image (image comes from backend)

Tags: javascript, image

My image path comes from backend and I get the image file with this path with new query:

```
const { data: image, isLoading: imageLoading, refetch: refetchiMAGE } = useGetFile({ path: photoCheck });
```

PhotoCheck is path that comes from data (backend) which describes user info.
The query is like :

```
export function useGetFile({ path }) {
  return useQuery(
    [QUERY_KEYS.files],
    async () => {
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.get('/v1/files/download', {
        params: {
          filePath: path,
        },
        responseType: 'blob',
      });
      return data;
    },
    { enabled: Boolean(path) },
  );
}
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(image);
      setImageSrc(imageUrl);
    }
  }, [data, image, photoCheck]);
```

After getting image file as blob I create a url and display it in image tag:

```
 {imageLoading ? <Loader /> : <img src={photoCheck === null ? Avatar : uploaded ? photoCheck : imageSrc} alt="profile" />}
```

If something is not uploaded yet this will show the image that uploaded :

```
  const uploadImage = e => {
    setUploaded(true);
    setPhotoCheck(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
    setUploadFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };
```

So when I upload a new photo and get submit I refetch data , and wait for a new image displaying,but image remains the same as like it was not uploaded,when I refresh the page image changes , how you can help me with this problem ?

I want image to change after upload but it does not

Comment: Please tag with relevant language and library/framework

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the _resulting_ page structure? Is it ultimately using `<img src="...">`? If so and the `src` doesn't change it could be that the browser is just showing you the image it already has cached from the page load.